# Help making an image expand and contract with the change in screen resolution

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution, image-scaling

I have a image of a shelf that I want to expand and contract with the change in width on the screen resolution.  The ends of the shelf have graphically designed images that must remain on the ends.  However, as the screen size changes, I want the center to fit the entire width of the shelf.  I have tried and can't seem to find a way to do this with all the different screen sizes.  You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SndhQ/. In this example, I changed the images to just colors to make it easy.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="shelf">
  <div class="shelfleft"></div>
  <div class="shelfline"></div>
  <div class="shelfright"></div>
</div>
```

and Here is the CSS:

```
.shelf{
float: left;
left: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
width: 79%;
}

.shelfleft{
background: red;
float: left;
height: 35px;
width: 19px;
}

.shelfline{
background: yellow;
float: left;
height: 35px;
margin-right: -10px;
width: 96%;
}

.shelfright{
background: blue;
float: right;
height: 35px;
width: 19px;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I only been coding for a few months.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jawad your link seems to be the same as the original

Comment: @tybro0103: Sorry, did not fork and save it. http://jsfiddle.net/gX8S3/

Comment: @Ryan Bennett: Position of absolute and float do not work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are sir:
http://jsfiddle.net/tybro0103/SndhQ/2/

You were on the right track, just a few changes:
1. Insert the "shelfright" div before the "shelfline" div.
2. drop the float and the width on shelfline (divs by default take up as much width as they can)
3. make shelfline's left and right margin's the same as the width of shelfleft and shelfright

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  So for my education, we didn't have to put a width for the shelfline because it was repeating and would take the width on the parent div?  We added margin so the left and right shelf would show.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes sir, more or less. If an element is display:block (divs are) and there is no float and no width, then it will take up as much width as it can. This is different than setting width:100%; however because without that margins, paddings, and borders are accounted for. With that set, the margins and such are added the width. And yes, floated elements can float within another element's margin, but for whatever reason the floated element must come before the margined element.